Access Error for Base Users on ir.attachment in Odoo 17
I'm encountering an access error in Odoo when trying to allow base users to read attachments (ir.attachment). Specifically, the error states that the user (id=6) does not have 'read' access to certain attachments, despite having created a record rule intended to grant this access.
ERROR MESSAGE
Uh-oh! Looks like you have stumbled upon some top-secret records.
Sorry, john (id=6) doesn't have 'read' access to:

Attachment, Bharathikannan Malaikkannan (1).pdf (ir.attachment: 1109)

Blame the following rules:

Allow Base Users to Read Attachments

Security rules:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!--  HR Announcement Multi Company rule -->
    <record id="hr_announcement_rule_company" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">HR Announcement Multi Company</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_announcement"/>
        <field eval="True" name="global"/>
        <field name="domain_force">
            ['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])]
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_hr_announcement_admin,access.hr.announcement.admin,model_hr_announcement,hr.group_hr_manager,1,1,1,1
access_hr_announcement_user,access.hr.announcement.user,model_hr_announcement,hr.group_hr_user,1,1,1,1
access_hr_announcement_employee,access.hr.announcement.employee,model_hr_announcement,base.group_user,1,0,0,0



**
my code Screen Shots is :**
Error Image
Field Declaration in Model Image
Access Method by employee_id by base user 
I expect that when a base user (like john with id=6) tries to access attachments in Odoo, they should be able to view all attachments without encountering any access errors. Specifically, I want them to see the following:
Attachment Name: Bharathikannan Malaikkannan (1).pdf
Access Level: The user should have 'read' access to this attachment and any others they have permissions for.

That's not how attachment rights usually work in Odoo. Attachments have
a specific implementation in regard to access rights. The access rights more or less reflect the access rights of the business models to which the attachments are attached.
For example: if a user has read rights to invoices (account.move), it can also read attached files to those invoices.
This special feature is mainly implemented by overriding the models.Model.check() method on model ir.attachment in module base.
For Odoo 16 the code, with some understandable comments:
@api.model
def check(self, mode, values=None):
    """ Restricts the access to an ir.attachment, according to referred mode """
    if self.env.is_superuser():
        return True
    # Always require an internal user (aka, employee) to access to a attachment
    if not (self.env.is_admin() or self.env.user._is_internal()):
        raise AccessError(_("Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document."))
    # collect the records to check (by model)
    model_ids = defaultdict(set)            # {model_name: set(ids)}
    if self:
        # DLE P173: `test_01_portal_attachment`
        self.env['ir.attachment'].flush_model(['res_model', 'res_id', 'create_uid', 'public', 'res_field'])
        self._cr.execute('SELECT res_model, res_id, create_uid, public, res_field FROM ir_attachment WHERE id IN %s', [tuple(self.ids)])
        for res_model, res_id, create_uid, public, res_field in self._cr.fetchall():
            if public and mode == 'read':
                continue
            if not self.env.is_system() and (res_field or (not res_id and create_uid != self.env.uid)):
                raise AccessError(_("Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document."))
            if not (res_model and res_id):
                continue
            model_ids[res_model].add(res_id)
    if values and values.get('res_model') and values.get('res_id'):
        model_ids[values['res_model']].add(values['res_id'])

    # check access rights on the records
    for res_model, res_ids in model_ids.items():
        # ignore attachments that are not attached to a resource anymore
        # when checking access rights (resource was deleted but attachment
        # was not)
        if res_model not in self.env:
            continue
        if res_model == 'res.users' and len(res_ids) == 1 and self.env.uid == list(res_ids)[0]:
            # by default a user cannot write on itself, despite the list of writeable fields
            # e.g. in the case of a user inserting an image into his image signature
            # we need to bypass this check which would needlessly throw us away
            continue
        records = self.env[res_model].browse(res_ids).exists()
        # For related models, check if we can write to the model, as unlinking
        # and creating attachments can be seen as an update to the model
        access_mode = 'write' if mode in ('create', 'unlink') else mode
        records.check_access_rights(access_mode)
        records.check_access_rule(access_mode)


not working can you provide detailly explanation

What do you mean by not working? That code example is from the odoo code. It's not meant to be used as "take that into your code". You're loading other model's attachments into your "hr.announcement" model. But access rights for "hr.announcement" won't do anything about the access rights on those attachments. For example: if you're loading an invoice attachment into "hr.announcement" and someone without accounting access will open it, this someone will get an access error.
